# How do I get my StringBuilder to append correctly?

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

The following code is being used as a generic event handler for 16 digit buttons on a hexadecimal calculator (0-9, A-F).

The following instructions define what I need to be accomplishing:

If the calculator is in display mode when a digit is pressed, that digit will replace the current content of the display and place the calculator in input mode. If the calculator is in input mode, there are three cases:

- If the content of the display is "0", the digit on the button pressed will replace the content of the display.
- Otherwise, if the content of the display contains fewer than eight characters (because we are dealing with 32-bit words), the digit on the button pressed will be appended to the content of the display.
- Otherwise, the button press is ignored.

One button press on my calculator will update the display correctly. However, if I press another button, instead of appending the StringBuilder with the new character, it will instead display a double character for the last button pressed. Eg. One press of 'C' will display a 'C'. A press of 'C' then say '8' will display '88'. Where is my problem here?

```
    public void ProcessClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StringBuilder _button = new StringBuilder();
        _button.Append(((Button)sender).Text);

        if (mode)
        {
            uxDisplay.Text = _button.ToString();
            mode = false;
        }
        else
        {
            if (uxDisplay.Text == "0")
            {
                uxDisplay.Text = _button.ToString();
            }
            else if (uxDisplay.Text.Length < 8)
            {
                uxDisplay.Text = _button.Append(((Button)sender).Text).ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be appending the value of `sender.Text` twice.

Here:

```
_button.Append(((Button)sender).Text);
```

and here:

```
uxDisplay.Text = _button.Append(((Button)sender).Text).ToString();
```

You are also creating a new StringBuilder on each call to Process so you aren't persisting the last value (apart from in the uxDisplay control)

How about something simple like:

```
...
else if (uxDisplay.Text.Length < 8)
{
    uxDisplay.Text += ((Button)sender).Text;
}
```

You are only appending a small number of strings so you won't really gain all that much performance from using a StringBuilder (especially if you create a new one on each call! :P )

Answer (score 0):

You are appending the pressed button text to your StringBuilder object directly after its creation, that's why you get twice the character.

You can go with something simple like this:

```
public void ProcessClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (mode)
    {
        uxDisplay.Text = _button.ToString();
        mode = false;
    }
    else
    {
        if (uxDisplay.Text == "0")
        {
            uxDisplay.Text = _button.ToString();
        }
        else if (uxDisplay.Text.Length < 8)
        {
            uxDisplay.Text += ((Button)sender).Text;
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```